# In react-native-webrtc in <RTCView> only video is coming, audio is not working

Tags: webrtc, react-native, getusermedia

I am working with react-native-webrtc but I am facing one problem I am able to display video captured by the camera but the audio is not working or we can say I am getting video frames of display and not able to listen any audio. I have given microphone access too and in getusermedia audio and video both parameters are true.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as mediasoupClient from 'mediasoup-client';
import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
registerGlobals();
class WebRtcScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    MediaStreamx: new MediaStream(),
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then(this.handleVideo)
      .catch(this.videoError);
  }

  handleVideo = (stream) => {
    this.setState({ MediaStreamx: stream });
  };

  videoError = (err) => {
    console.log(err.name);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <RTCView
        key={1}
        zOrder={2}
        objectFit="cover"
        style={{ ...styles.rtcView }}
        streamURL={this.state.MediaStreamx.toURL()}
      />
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rtcView: {
    width: 100, //dimensions.width,
    height: 200, //dimensions.height / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
});

export { WebRtcScreen };
```

Why is the audio not working here?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to be more specific about your "audio is not working" problem? It's common for getUserMedia subsystems to suppress local output from the microphone to avoid squealing feedback. Could that be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that react-native-webrtc plays audio in earphone. You need to use 
https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager
to play audio in phone speaker.

Hope this helps.